# How to distribute PowerPoint AddIn/PPAM while still able to update

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have developed a custom Addin to PowerPoint and I am trying to come up with a solution for how to distribute it in an easy way.
My initial plan was to place the addin (.ppam) in a central drive and have the users add it from there, unfortunately it does not seem like I can update it, that is save a new copy of it on the existing location, if the users have opened it (despite having set it to read only). This can be done with Excel Addins by a script like the following.

```
Sub DeployAddIn()
'Test
Dim strNewName As String
'Author       : Ken Puls (www.excelguru.ca)
'Macro Purpose: To deploy finished/updated add-in to a network
'               location as a read only file
    Dim strAddinDevelopmentPath As String
    Dim strAddinPublicPath As String

    'Set development and public paths
    strAddinDevelopmentPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    strAddinPublicPath = "C:\Public Path" & Application.PathSeparator

    'Turn off alert regarding overwriting existing files
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False


    'Save the add-in
    With ThisWorkbook
    strNewName = Left(.Name, InStrRev(.Name, "-") - 1) & "." & Right(.Name, (Len(.Name) - InStrRev(.Name, ".")))
        'Save to ensure work is okay in case of a crash
        .Save

        'Save read only copy to the network (remove read only property
        'save the file and reapply the read only status)
        On Error Resume Next
        SetAttr strAddinPublicPath & strNewName, vbNormal
        On Error GoTo 0
        .SaveCopyAs FileName:=strAddinPublicPath & strNewName
        SetAttr strAddinPublicPath & strNewName, vbReadOnly
    End With

    'Resume alerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Anyone have any thoughts on how to distribute a PowerPoint addin in a clever way?

EDIT: Updated with solution
I ended up using a two-part Addin as I cannot be certain users are allowed to run EXE/MSI files. Essentially my build is like

```
Const strCentralPath As String = Central path

Sub Auto_Open()
Dim objAddins As AddIns
Dim objAddIn As AddIn
Dim dblCurrentVersion As Double
Dim dblMyVersion As Double

Set objAddins = Application.AddIns
'Check if Addin is already added and loaded.
'If it is, check if version is same as local.
For Each objAddIn In objAddins
    If objAddIn.Name = "Name of addin" Then
        If objAddIn.Loaded = msoCTrue Then objAddIn.Loaded = msoCTrue
        GoTo CheckVersion
    End If

Next objAddIn

'If addin is not found add it
Call AddAddin
GoTo ExitLine


'Check version
CheckVersion:
dblCurrentVersion = Version(strCentralPath)
dblMyVersion = Version(local path)

If dblCurrentVersion > dblMyVersion Then
    Application.AddIns(Name of addin).Loaded = msoFalse
    Call AddAddin 'If version is lower, unload and add the the new one.
End If

ExitLine:

Set objAddins = Nothing


End Sub

Function Version(Path As String) As Double

Dim fso As Object
Dim dblDate As Integer

Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
intDate = CDbl(fso.GetFile(Path).DateCreated)
Version = intDate

Set fso = Nothing


End Function

Sub AddAddin()
Dim strAddInLocalPath As String
Dim strAddinCentralPath As String
Dim fso As Object

'Get local path
strAddInLocalPath = local path

Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("scripting.Filesystemobject")

DeleteFile strAddInLocalPath

Call fso.CopyFile(strCentralPath, strAddInLocalPath, True)
SetAttr strAddInLocalPath, vbReadOnly

With Application.AddIns.Add(strAddInLocalPath)
    .Loaded = msoCTrue
End With

Set fso = Nothing

End Sub

Sub DeleteFile(ByVal FileToDelete As String)
   If FileExists(FileToDelete) Then 'See above
      SetAttr FileToDelete, vbNormal
      Kill FileToDelete
   End If
End Sub

Function FileExists(ByVal FileToTest As String) As Boolean
   FileExists = (Dir(FileToTest) <> "")
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try to let multiple users load the same add-in file.

If the users can doubleclick an EXE or MSI installer, that's one way to distribute updates.  Since Advanced Installer was mentioned, I'll add that it will produce either and is a *very* capable tool, and very well supported.

Another approach is to have a log-in script download the current version of the addin from a centralized location to each user's local computer. It would then be on the system before the user can start PPT, so no conflicts.

In theory, you could have Add-in A installed and when it auto-runs, it looks at the date of Add-in B's PPA/PPAM file and if there's a newer version "Out There", copies it to the local add-in folder.  Then either way, demand-loads Addin B, which does the real work.  Seems like a lot of trouble to go through when the previous approach would, I think, work just as well.

Comment: I have marked this as the answer, as it outlines the two basic solutions I also arrived at. I ended up using the two-part Addin approach since I cannot be sure that users are allowed to run EXE/MSI files.

Answer (score 1):

I know I need to face the same issue shortly and have been thinking about two options. Firstly to build the add-in into an MSI installer package which I believe can manage this updating element automatically (I'm evaluating [the Advanced Installer solution](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/addins-tab.html)). Secondly, I wonder if I can build a two add-in architecture whereby the first one loads without any UI and it's sole purpose tis to download the main one from a remote location. However, I don't think there's a way to determine the load order of application add-ins (even though it seems to be alphabetic). I think this is what you're trying to do?

Comment: Building an MSI is very easy and this makes the deployment straightforward for your add-in. The folks from the IT department (application management/deployment team) will simply get the MSI and use SCCM to push it to all the users requesting it.

If an user has rights to install it for himself, he can just double click the MSI to launch the installation. (have a basic UI MSI build, so they don't need to pass through all the steps of accepting EULA, selecting instal folder, ....)

Comment: So when you need to update the addin you simply push the .exe file again?  
If yes, this could be a solution, albeit it is less elegant than the Excel solution but I have run out of ideas on how to mimic this.

A two-addin system can be done, and I was thinking along those lines myself. You can test the name of the addin so you can still identify which addin you are handeling. Then simply copy the addin to a local path on the users computer and update it when needed remotely.

Comment: Yes, for this Advanced Installer has a built-in automatic updater which you can enable to be included into your MSI/EXE. This updater can be triggered by a scheduled task for example, to automatically check for new versions and install them, without user intervention or with full UI. http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/updater-diagram.html